# Linux - Monitor remote commands with "script"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, monitoring

I'm using `script` command in Linux to monitor everything done in my bash, and saving the results in `myFile.log`, and errors in `log.err`.

I set it in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
script -qtf 2> log.err myFile.log
```

Where parameters:

- `-q`: Do not show the file that is saved
- `-t`: Shows the error in another file
- `-f`: Shows the log in real time

I've noted that when I execute remote commands, $TERM environment variable is not recognized, and some specific (and important) application commands are not executed.

To solve the problem, I used "-c" parameter to interpret those commands that need interaction with env vars. But when I use it, my files are not written!

I set it in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
script -qtfc 2> log.err myFile.log
```

What is happening?

Is there a better way (I'm sure that is) to do this monitoring and log it all into files?

Answer (score 0):

> `-c, --command command`
>
> Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.

Command option expects argument. If you write it this way (`script -qtfc 2> log.err myFile.log`), the command used is `2>` which is certainly not what you want.

What command is run, is probably in the bash variable `$*` so possible approach is `script -qtfc "$*" 2> log.err myFile.log`